# How to grab Image url and title from elements above in same article

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Hi Guys i got a question.
How can I get onclick the image url and title from divs in my webpage?

This is the structure of the article:

```
        <article class="white-panel">
             <img src="image url to grab" alt="">
             <h4><a href="#">Title to grab</a></h4>
             <p><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-whatsapp"></span> Onclick grab image and title with Jquery</a></p>
             <p><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Auf Facebook teilen</a></p>
       </article>
```

I need this for several article elements on page but they all got the same sructure.

Comment: Unclear. You're wondering what jQuery selector will give you the span containing `Onclick grab image...`? I don't see a `div` in your markup

Comment: I don't see any `div`s do you mean `article`? Or all elements under `body`. Be more specific.

Comment: Are you asking for the jQuery selector or function, or are you wanting pure Javascript?

Comment: Sorry mean article

Comment: asking for the function @TheValyreanGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of all these articles is the same, the following should work:

```
$('article p:first-of-type a').click(function() {
    // Get the parent article of the clicked link
    var parentArticle = $(this).parents('article');
    // Find the img src and h4 (title) text
    console.log($(parentArticle).find('img').prop('src'));
    console.log($(parentArticle).find('h4 a').text());
});
```

The `console.log()` is just to see the values, you could store these in variables for further use.

Comment: Oh jeez I just saw this answer... I guess I wasted my time. Here's an upvote for getting there faster.

Comment: Hey @Jonathan Michalik how to implement it in whatsapp share code ?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking to implement.  If it's related to your initial question, you can update the question.  If the question is noticeably different, I'd suggest asking a new question, you'll get more eyes on the question then and the title of the question will help others find it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you're after the src and alt of all the imgs in your article, you might want to try something like this.

```
$('article').each(function(in,elem){
    var img = elem.children('img').attr('src');
    var title = elem.children('h4').text();
    // Code that does something with them
})
```

Comment: No I want the img src and the h4 of the artivle in it

Comment: Changed accordingly.

Comment: so this code does not grab the h4 inside and is only working with one element not several elements

Comment: No, this code executes on every article on page and returns the src attribute of the img and the text within the h4. Is that what you needed?

Comment: I just tried this out and I'm a little surprised it works.  The text for the `h4` is actually in an anchor tag.  Calling `$('h4').text()` and `$('h4 a').text()` return the same correct value.  Interesting!

Comment: Yeah, if I'm correct, it just returns the text nodes, regardless of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The no jQuery version just in case.

```
var articleList = document.getElementsByClassName('white-panel');
var imageList = new Array();

Array.prototype.slice.call(articleList).forEach(function(value, index) {
    imageList.push({
        url: value.src,
        title: value.title
    });
});
```